# make "load more" on scroll bottom works with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have this snippet that works great with jquery alone,when i try to use it with jquery mobile it doesn't works properly .
when i preview the page im creating using ripple emulator im saying two scroll bars, one in the right side and the other on the left side .
when i scroll the left one (scroll of content) it doesn't fire the load more content (that's the problem) , but when i load the left one ; bottom or top (I HAVE TO SCROLL BOTTOM AND RIGHTS MANY TIMES )it fires the load content many times ..

this is the code im using :

```html
<script>
var currentPage = 2,
    loadThreshold = 20; //50px threshold used to define when it needs to load more items.

$( window ).scroll(function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
      containerHeight = $(document).height(),
      contentCurrentTopPosition = $(document).scrollTop(),
      deltaDistanceToContentBottom = containerHeight - windowHeight - contentCurrentTopPosition;


    if (deltaDistanceToContentBottom < loadThreshold){
        getData(currentPage);
        currentPage++;
    }

});
  </script>
```

any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

I avoid handling the scroll event; I prefer to use a timer:

```
updateTimer = setInterval(function() {
    var $w = $(window);
    if (oldw !== $w.width() || oldh !== $w.height() ||
            oldt !== $w.scrollTop()) {
        oldw = $w.width();
        oldh = $w.height();
        oldt = $w.scrollTop();
        ...
    }
}, 250);
```

Comment: i didn't understood the idea you're trying to acheive @Maurice

Comment: @Hamzar do something when the window is either scrolled or resized.

Comment: Well, every 1/4 second, it tests if the width, height, or scrollTop has changed since last check, in which case it does whatever the hell is needed (like loading the data needed to render the visible area of the window), otherwise it does nothing.

Comment: The reason I'm going through this trouble is that the scroll event is not handled uniformly across browsers.